Spring Boot connect to SQL Server database using Windows Authentication on port other than 1433
I am using Java Spring Boot 3.3.0 in IntelliJ.
For dependencies, I added "Spring Data JDBC" and "MS SQL Server Driver".
Do I need to add other dependencies?
This is what I have for dependencies in build.gradle:
dependencies {
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'


Our SQL Server database is not on port 1433, it's on a different port, say port 12345.
How can I connect to it on port 12345?
Also, how can I connect using Windows Authentication?

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:sqlserver://myServer:12345;databaseName=myDb;integratedSecurity=true

Is that connection string correct?
I am getting this error running it
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: 
Error creating bean with name 'jdbcMappingContext' defined in class path 
resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/
JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: 
Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'jdbcMappingContext' parameter 1: Error 
creating bean with name 'jdbcCustomConversions' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/
JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: 
Failed to instantiate 
[org.springframework.data.jdbc.core.convert.JdbcCustomConversions]: 
Factory method 'jdbcCustomConversions' threw exception with message: Error creating 
bean with name 'jdbcDialect' defined in class path resource 
[org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/data/jdbc/
JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration$SpringBootJdbcConfiguration.class]: 
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.data.relational.core.dialect.Dialect]: 
Factory method 'jdbcDialect' threw exception with message: 
Failed to obtain JDBC Connection

Thank you in advance

Based on your error you are missing a bunch of dependencies. I imagine if you read the readmes it will mention them

where is the readmes ?
And, how about my 2 questions about the connection string for sql server with port other than 1433 and windows authentication ?

Your connection string looks fine, but you need to include the actual error, the above error is just the pizza toppings. I'm guessing either port is not correct or it's not open but hard to say, could be that you're missing the windows auth dll in class path

If you want to use domain auth from windows, you need jdts:
Dependencies:
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
            <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

application.yml
spring:
  datasource:
    password: ${MSSQL_DB_PASSWORD}
    url: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://sqlsrv:12345;domain=WORKGROUP;trustServerCertificate=true;loginTimeout=30;
    username: DBUsername


You might need to update the domain and username.

No need to use jtds for windows auth, if you include the mssqlserver auth-dll

I was going to ask if there is another way besides using jtds. How can I include mssqlserver auth-dll ? I edited my original post by adding the dependencies that I have in the project. Thank you
